# Sort column by values in ui.Chart.feature.byProperty in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart, sorting

I am creating a bar chart of band importance of a random forest classifier in GEE. The default bar order seems to be by name. How can I **sort the columns in descending order** depending on each column value?

This is the code I am using to create the chart:

```js
// classifier information
var exp = classifier.explain();
print('RF explained', exp);


var band_importance = ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary(exp).get('importance'));

var chart =
ui.Chart.feature.byProperty(band_importance)
.setChartType('ColumnChart')
.setOptions({
title: 'Random forest band importance',
legend: {position: 'none'},
hAxis: {title: 'Bands'},
vAxis: {title: 'Importance'}
});
 
print(chart);
```

This is the resulting chart:
[image: chart:]

This is the link to the code: [example](https://code.earthengine.google.com/948ba773adfe6a3cf1161c4a1da36839)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries (and Feature properties) aren't ordered, so you have to jump through some hoops to convert them into something that has an order first.

Get the importance keys and values as lists, sort them, convert to a Chart API [DataTable](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/charts_datatable#manual_datatable_chart) and plot that:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/4ae6b783c20dc09aed826a358b94552f

```
var importance = ee.Dictionary(exp.get('importance'))
var keys = importance.keys().sort(importance.values()).reverse()
var values = importance.values(keys);
var rows = keys.zip(values).map(function(list) {
  return {c: ee.List(list).map(function(n) { return {v: n}; })}
})

var dataTable = {
  cols: [{id: 'band', label: 'Band', type: 'string'},
         {id: 'importance', label: 'Importance', type: 'number'}],
  rows: rows.getInfo()
};
```